# Drop down "context" menu appearing in Eclipse that I can't get rid of

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, contextmenu

A few days again, a new drop-down auto-complete menu started showing up in Eclipse. I have no idea how I turned it on, I don't find it useful, and I can't figure out for the life of me how to get rid of it. It will show up on top of Eclipse's "Content Assist" menu, which I actually do use, and also causes every word I type to blink after I finish typing it.

Please, someone tell me you've seen this before and you know how to make it go away.

[image: Screen shot showing drop down menu in eclipse]

Note to mods: if this doesn't belong here, please tell me where I can get this question answered! It's driving me NUTS!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Eclipse you are running, I have had a similar issue with a JavaScript auto-complete plug-in not finding what I was typing.  This behavior was truly annoying because I would get a Java Exception dialog almost every time I would type something related to JavaScript, and I would have to acknowledge it every single time.  There was something good about my situation, though.  The Exception dialog told me that if I wanted this dialog to go away (which I most certainly did) I would need to disable the JavaScript plug-in associated with it.

So while this is probably a scorched earth type of solution to your problem, try disabling plug-ins to see if the auto-complete dialog goes away.